# Problems in understating execution flow in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2, oncreate

The following code is using retrofit and youtubedata api to get subscriber count of two youtube channels.

```
public class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private static String GOOGLE_YOUTUBE_API_KEY = "AIzaSyBV4XQEZ9l1HZeBQFL6ZZvHYfMhtnqUkmw";
private static String CHANNEL_ID_TS = "UCq-Fj5jknLsUf-MWSy4_brA";
private static String CHANNEL_ID_PDP = "UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw";
public static int SUBS_TS = 0;
public static int SUBS_PDP = 0;

//?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&id=UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw&key=AIzaSyBV4XQEZ9l1HZeBQFL6ZZvHYfMhtnqUkmw

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

    Map<String, String> qMap = new HashMap<>();
    qMap.put("part", "snippet,contentDetails,statistics");
    qMap.put("id", CHANNEL_ID_TS);
    qMap.put("key", GOOGLE_YOUTUBE_API_KEY);


    Map<String, String> qMap2 = new HashMap<>();
    qMap2.put("part", "snippet,contentDetails,statistics");
    qMap2.put("id", CHANNEL_ID_PDP);
    qMap2.put("key", GOOGLE_YOUTUBE_API_KEY);

    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<ChannelResponse> call = apiService.getSubs(qMap);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ChannelResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ChannelResponse> call, Response<ChannelResponse> response) {

                List<Channel> channels = response.body().getChannels();
                SUBS_TS = channels.get(0).getStatistics().getSubscriberCount();
                Log.d("GEEK", SUBS_TS + "");

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ChannelResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("GEEK", t.toString());
            }
        });


        Call<ChannelResponse> call2 = apiService.getSubs(qMap2);
        call2.enqueue(new Callback<ChannelResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ChannelResponse> call, Response<ChannelResponse> response) {

                List<Channel> channels = response.body().getChannels();
                SUBS_PDP = channels.get(0).getStatistics().getSubscriberCount();
                Log.d("GEEK", SUBS_PDP + "");

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ChannelResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("GEEK", t.toString());
            }
        });

        //This statement seems to be executed before the SUSB_TS and SUSB_PDP variables are updated using the response. 
        Log.d("GEEK", SUBS_PDP + "AFTER");

}
```

}

Why is the

```
Log.d("GEEK", SUBS_PDP + "AFTER");
```

statement executed before the onResponse method?

Log

```
2018-12-12 14:30:26.993 17518-17518/com.geek.wartube D/GEEK: 0AFTER
2018-12-12 14:30:27.863 17518-17518/com.geek.wartube D/GEEK: 76222082
2018-12-12 14:30:27.885 17518-17518/com.geek.wartube D/GEEK: 75161493
```

I have also checked using the debugger that statements inside onResponse were not executed before the log statement in last line.

---

**What should I do to achieve the desired result?**

Comment: I think you must not mention your youtube API key ..... Remove it, as it is not safe

Comment: @Deepanshutyagi I will disable it very soon

Comment: the the methods you enqueue are put on a different thread. the code fires those threads and the current thread jumps to the next available line of code it has to follow, in this case the log. by the time the log is printed the methods on the other threads get executed and thus your log gets printed below your "after" log.

Answer (score 1):

The calls to apiService.getSubs(qMap) and apiService.getSubs(qMap2) methods are done in background thread. That's why the next statement is executed before response finishes. Hence statement Log.d("GEEK", SUBS_PDP + "AFTER"); executes before onResponse() method

You can execute second call in onResponse() of first call and in onResponse() of second call do whatever you want to do next or if possible use Rxjava. But first way is simple to understand

Comment: Your suggested method will not work as the statement is executed before both of them

Comment: Create a function and check in it, that SUBS_TS , SUBS_PDP are not equal to zero then do what you want, call that function in both responses at the bottom.

Comment: That's why I told you to put the statement in onResponse() of second call